# Random number issue in golang

Tags: go, random

This is the code I'm working with:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "math/rand"

func main() {
    code := rand.Intn(900000)
    fmt.Println(code)
}
```

It always prints `698081`. What the is problem?

> https://play.golang.org/p/XisNbqCZls

**Edit**:

I tried `rand.Seed`

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "math/rand"

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    code := rand.Intn(900000)
    fmt.Println(code)
}
```

There is no change. Now it always prints `452000`

> https://play.golang.org/p/E_Wfm5tOdH
>
> https://play.golang.org/p/aVWIN1Eb84

Comment: Default random number generators in all programming languages, produce the same sequence with a specific seed number. Because these packages are meant to be used mainly for testing algorithms (when we need to check the result against the same input) or just as a semi-random number when used with time element. If you want a real random number, you should use the one from crypto package.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A couple of reasons why you'll see the same result in the playground

1. Golang playground will cache the results
2. The time in the playground always starts at the same time to make the playground deterministic.

Last but not least, the `rand` package default seed is `1` which will make the result deterministic. If you place a `rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())` you'll receive different results at each execution. Note that this won't work on the playground for the second reason above.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/E_Wfm5tOdH -  https://play.golang.org/p/aVWIN1Eb84
there is no change. now both of links always returns 452000

Comment: Correct, because `time.Now()` will always return the same value in every playground to make it deterministic. Try printing that value out and you'll see why. You have to try it from your machine.

Comment: Ok, i got it. The problem is resolved. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Despite of using `rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())` it gives the same result even if  I hit "**Run**" multiple times. In the playground, it also says _"Time is constant in the playground"_ so I assume `rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())` will give same value everytime.

Comment: Interestingly, on Google App Engine there is no problem (the random numbers are different every time) even without doing this.

Comment: This is deprecated on version 1.20+